# Get data from controller into same view page in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch messages when user clicks on a specific chat (you can say div which has hidden input fields for ids) just like messenger. The view is same on which i'm sending the data. First time when inbox opens up a chat list is added at the left side and the right is blank until user clicks on a chat.
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Here is my code from which I get id when user clicks on the specific chatlist. I get ids through which i can fetch all messages. I'm using different models as I've different queries for both.
I dont know how to get json data which i got from ajax into php variable so that  I've to loop through and display messages.
Attaching codes and pictures for references.

Model

```
public function get_msg($employer_id)
 {
   $query1 = $this->db->select()
   ->where('msg_from_id', $employer_id)
   ->group_by('msg_from',$employer_id)
   ->from('inbox')
   ->get('');

   return $query1->result();
 }
public function get_all_msgs($msg_from_id,$msg_to_id)
 {
  $conditions = array('msg_from_id' => $msg_from_id, 'msg_to_id' => 
   $msg_to_id);

   $query1 = $this->db->select()
      ->where($conditions)
      ->from('inbox')
      ->get('');

    return $query1->result_array();
 }
```

Controller:

```
public function get_all_msgs()
 {
   $postData = $this->input->post();
   $msg_to_id= $postData['msg_to_id'];
   $msg_from_id=$postData['msg_from_id'];

   $this->load->model('employermodel');

   $get_all_msgs=$this->employermodel->get_all_msgs($msg_from_id,$msg_to_id);
    if($get_all_msgs!=NULL){
      echo json_encode($get_all_msgs);
  }
}
public function inbox(){

  $emp = $this->session->userdata('user_email');
  $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

  $employer_id=$emp_id;
  if($emp_id == NULL){
  return redirect('users/index');
  }

$this->load->model('employermodel');
$get_msgs=$this->employermodel->get_msg($employer_id);
if($get_msgs!=NULL){

  $this->load->view('inbox',['get_msgs'=>$get_msgs,]);
  
}
```

}

Javascript/ajax on same view page i.e. "Inbox" :

```
$('.msgs-ConversationListPane').click(function (e) {

    if ($('.msgs-ConversationListPane').hasClass('is-active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');
        $('.msgs-ConversationPane').addClass('is-active');
        $('.msgs-ConversationPane').removeClass('is-splash');
        // $('.msgs-ConversationPane').load('.msgs-Conversation'.href);
        $(".msgs-ConversationPane").html($("." + $(this).attr('rel')).html());

        var msg_to_id = $('#msg_to_id').val();
        var msg_from_id = $('#msg_from').val();
        var get_all_msgs;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'<?=base_url()?>employer/get_all_msgs',
             data: {msg_to_id: msg_to_id,
                msg_from_id:msg_from_id},
                dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // JSON.stringify
                get_all_msgs = data;
                $("#res").html(get_all_msgs);
                // console.log(get_all_msgs);
                $(".msgs-ConversationPane").css('display', 'block');
               
            },
            
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
                },
        
        })
        // .done(function(get_all_msgs) {
        
        ;
    } else if ($('.msgs-ConversationPane').hasClass('is-splash')) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-splash');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
        $('.msgs-ConversationListPane').addClass('is-splash');
        $('.msgs-ConversationListPane').removeClass('is-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Share your code in text format instead of pictures / images.

Comment: Edited. Please check. And before down voting see that I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to get the json data into a php variable. Php is executed server side, ajax is executed client side. The benefit of ajax usage is to dynamicly change the content after server execution is finished. You want to update the screen content via JavaScript (So only on the users end).
The next step is to extract the json data and to add a message div to the message container div.